# Error with 0 point layer in lidR

Tags: r, lidr

I have LiDAR point cloud from 26 X 1 ha forest plots. I am trying to calculate roughness index for different vegetation layers in each plot with following code using `lidR` package.

```
files <- list.files(path= "FilesDirectory/", pattern= "*.laz", full.names = TRUE, recursive = FALSE)
O = lapply(files, function(x) {

  las = readLAS(x, select = "xyzc", filter = "-drop_z_below 0")

  las_l1 = lasfilter(las, las$Z <= 1.0) #first vegetation layer <= 1 m
  las_l2 <- lasfilter(las, las$Z > 1.0 & las$Z <=8.0) # 8.0 >= second layer >1
  las_l3 <- lasfilter(las, las$Z > 8.0) # and third layer > 8.0

  chm_l1 = grid_canopy(las_l1, 0.2, p2r())
  chm_l2 = grid_canopy(las_l2, 0.2, p2r())
  chm_l3 = grid_canopy(las_l3, 0.2, p2r())


  roughness_l1 <- rumple_index(chm_l1)
  roughness_l2 <- rumple_index(chm_l2)
  roughness_l3 <- rumple_index(chm_l3)

  return(data.frame(file=x, roughness_l1=roughness_l1,roughness_l2=roughness_l2,
                    roughness_l3=roughness_l3))
})
```

However, this code is returning error

```
Error: The point cloud contains 0 point
```

I think the cause of error could be that in some files there may not be any point on the third layer. Therefore, I want to include if condition that if the the third layer doesn't have any point `print ("no points on third layer")` otherwise calculate `chm_l3` for the third layer with following code.

```
if (length(las_l3)==0) {"no points on third layer"} else {chm_l3 = grid_canopy(las_l3, 0.2, p2r())}
```

But it didn't help.

Comment: When you say that code "didn't help", did it do anything? Did you detect any files with no points in the third layer? Do you know which file this was? Can you run your function one line at a time on that file only and see what happens?

Comment: `npoints(las)` returns the number of points in a `LAS` object, not `length(las)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `is.empty`

```
if (is.empty(las_l1)) {
    roughness_l1 <- NA
} else {
    chm_l1 <- grid_canopy(las_l1, 0.2, p2r())
    roughness_l1 <- rumple_index(chm_l1)
}
```

`npoints` can also be used instead of `length`

Also notice that you can write

```
las_l1 = lasfilter(las, Z <= 1.0)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @JRR, it worked.